# Animate itemView in RecyclerView with View.animate()

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation, objectanimator

I have an Adapter which has a text. A CountDownTimer is used to add data to the adapter every 1 second, and notifyItemInserted. When onBindViewHolder, the following codes are run:

```
sampleItemView.setText(text)
        val animatorY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sampleItemView, "translationY", 1000f, 1f)
        val animatorX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sampleItemView, "translationX", 1000f, 1f)
        val set = AnimatorSet()
        set.playTogether(animatorX, animatorY)
        set.duration = 2000
        set.start()
```

The animation is successfully performed.
But when I change to

```
sampleItemView.animate()
                    .setInterpolator(LinearInterpolator())
                    .translationXBy(1000f)
                    .translationYBy(1000f)
                    .setDuration(2000)
                    .setUpdateListener({
                        println("x($text): ${sampleItemView.x}")
                        println("y($text): ${sampleItemView.y}")
                    })
                    .start()
```

The animation cannot be run. What's the difference with the above two pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference with the above two pieces of code?

Conceptually they look very alike. Nevertheless, there exists a subtle difference.

With following statement:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sampleItemView, "translationY", 1000f, 1f)
```

you tell: "animate `translationY` property from value 1000 to 1".

On the other hand, with following statement:

```
translationYBy(1000f)
```

you are telling: "animate `translationY` property from **current** value to **current + 1000**".

Thus, they are **not** equal.

This animation would be equal to the initial one:

```
    view.animate()
        .withStartAction(() -> {
              view.setTranslationX(1000);
              view.setTranslationY(1000);
            })
        .translationX(1)
        .translationY(1)
        ...
```

Pay attention, `translationY()` is used instead of `translationYBy()`.